# Drag and Drop element into second ul makes it null

Tags: javascript

I create this element through a form thats submitted. Then once this element is created i want it to have the same drag and drop functionality as placeholder values i originally had. But for some reason once its dragged, the item then later becomes "null" once its moved to the second ul. Not sure how I can make sure the item dragged keeps all its data, or stays the same both in the front end and in the dom once its moved.

```js
var foodItems = document.querySelectorAll('.food_item');
    const foodList = document.querySelectorAll('.food_list');
    const form = document.querySelector('form');
    const ul = document.querySelector('ul');
    const clearBtn = document.querySelector('.clear_btn');
    const formInput = document.querySelector('.form_control');
    const feedback = document.querySelector('.feedback');
    const danger = document.querySelector('.danger');
    const success = document.querySelector('.success');
    const input = document.getElementById('input');
    const checkBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.fa-check-circle');
    const deleteBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.fa-edit');
    
    const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('foods'));
    
    // load local storage
    
    var foodsArray;
        
    if(localStorage.getItem('foods')){
        foodsArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('foods'))
    } else {
        foodsArray = [];
    }
    
    foodsArray.forEach(div => {
        liMaker(div)
    });
    
    // create li item
    
    function liMaker(text){
       const div = document.createElement('div');
        div.textContent = text;
        div.classList.add('food_item');
        var child1 = document.createElement('span');
        child1.className = 'far fa-check-circle';
        child1.addEventListener('click', checkBtnHandler);
        div.appendChild(child1);
        var child2 = document.createElement('span');
        child2.className = 'far fa-edit';
        child2.addEventListener('click', deleteBtnHandler);
        div.appendChild(child2);
        document.querySelector('.food_list').append(div);
    }
    
    
    
    form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    
        const value = document.getElementById('input').value;
    
        if(value == ''){
            document.querySelector('.success').style.display = 'none';
            document.querySelector('.danger').style.display = 'block';
            setTimeout(function(){
                document.querySelector('.danger').style.display = 'none';
            }, 2000)
        } else {
            document.querySelector('.danger').style.display = 'none';
            document.querySelector('.success').style.display = 'block';
            foodsArray.push(input.value)
            localStorage.setItem('foods', JSON.stringify(foodsArray))
            liMaker(input.value);
            input.value = '';
            setTimeout(function(){
                document.querySelector('.success').style.display = 'none';
            }, 2000)
        }
    })
    
    // clear btn functionality
    
    clearBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
        localStorage.clear()
        item = document.querySelector('.food_list');
        while(item.firstChild){
            item.removeChild(item.firstChild)
        }
    })
    
    // delete btn functionality
    
    function deleteBtnHandler(e){
        const div = e.currentTarget.parentNode;
        var index = [].indexOf.call(div.parentNode.children, div)
        foodsArray.splice(index, 1);
         localStorage.setItem('foods', JSON.stringify(foodsArray));
        div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
    }
    
    function checkBtnHandler(e) {
        const underline = e.currentTarget.parentNode;
        underline.classList.toggle('completed');
      }
    
    
    // button event listener functionlity
    
    
    deleteBtns.forEach(function(btn) {
        btn.addEventListener('click', deleteBtnHandler);
      
      });
      
      checkBtns.forEach(function(btn) {
        btn.addEventListener('click', checkBtnHandler);
      });
    
    // drag drop functionality
           
    let draggedItem = null;
    
    foodItems.forEach(function(e, i){
    const item = listItems[i];
    
    item.addEventListener('dragstart', function (e){
        e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
        e.dataTransfer.setData('text', item.innerHTML);
        draggedItem = item;
        setTimeout(function(){
            item.style.display = 'none';
        }, 0)
    });
    
    item.addEventListener('dragend', function(){
        setTimeout(function() {
            draggedItem.style.display = 'block';
           draggedItem = null;
        }, 0);
    });
    
    });
    
    foodList.forEach(function(list){
        list.addEventListener('dragover', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    
        list.addEventListener('dragenter', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            this.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)';
        
        });
    
        list.addEventListener('dragleave', function(e){
            this.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)';
        })
       
    
        list.addEventListener('drop', function(e){
            list.append(draggedItem);
            this.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)';
        });
    })
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div class="container">    
      <div class="input_group">
          <form class="form_input">
    <input type="text" class="form_control" id="input" placeholder="food name...">
    <button class="btn_submit" type="submit">add item</button>    
    
    </form><!-- form input-->
    </div><!--input group-->
    
      <ul class="lists">
        <div class="food_list"></div>    
        <div class="food_list"></div>
      </ul>
      
    <div class="button_container">
      <button class="clear_btn">Clear All</button>
    </div>
    
    </div><!--container-->    
     <script src="js/drag.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I can't give you a straight answer, but I can help you start fixing small stuff that should unravel some of the mystery.  So first off all your html collection foodItems is empty when you try to bind your eventlisteners to the items. The items are created after the querySelector runs. The optimal thing would be to bind the event listeners to the items at their creation, in liMaker() for example.

Comment: The second thing is that draggable isn't set on any item which will limit the draggability, if that's a word... read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/draggable for exacted information.
<div class="food_list" draggable="true"></div>

Comment: do you mean I should bind the dragstart and dragend? because those are the only event listeners on the food_items

Comment: that fixed it fubar, thanks again

Comment: in general you want to bind the eventlistener to the element at creation since then you only have to loop once and every thing is clean and tidy.